# Script to start Android LineageOS with Waydroid in an X11 session

Tags: x11, xorg, android, window-manager, wayland

I would like to make a script to start the [Waydroid](https://waydro.id/) Android container (LineageOS).

Currently, I can start a [LineageOS](https://lineageos.org/) virtual phone without issues with:

```
sudo systemctl start waydroid-container
weston
```

And then, inside the `weston-terminal`:

```
waydroid session start
waydroid show-full-ui
```

Note that Waydroid only works in a Wayland session manager, and the [Weston compositor](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/weston/-/blob/master/README.md) is a [simple way](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Waydroid#Wayland_session_manager)
to run it with your ordinary X windows manager.

I do not know how should I insert the last two lines in the  Bash launcher script. I tried to export

```
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
```

but, while the Waydroid session starts, I am clueless on how to push the phone GUI to the Weston compositor.

There are of course X11 solutions, such as [Anbox](https://anbox.io/)
but Waydroid shines in comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable to send Waydroid *in place* (i.e. inside Weston) is `WAYLAND_DISPLAY`
not `XDG_SESSION_TYPE`.
Also, the [XWayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server#XWayland) server should be activated.

So, make sure that the Waydroid container is on:

```
systemctl start waydroid-container
```

Now, you can launch your phone from your terminal/script with:

```
weston --xwayland &
export WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-1              
sleep 2
waydroid show-full-ui &
```

Rather than kill Waydroid, a better way to close the phone:

```
waydroid session stop
```

and Ctrl+Alt+Backspace to quit Weston.

For HiDPI diplay, you might add `--scale 2` argument to Weston.

Answer (score 1):

This is a script I found here [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/qs9c9s/comment/ikvilso/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) . Hope it helps. Also if it works for you let me know, Im in a similar position too.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
if [ "$(systemctl is-active waydroid-container.service)" == 'active' ];then
    killall -9 weston
    sudo systemctl stop waydroid-container.service
    exit
fi
killall -9 weston
sudo systemctl restart waydroid-container.service
if [ -z "$(pgrep weston)" ]; then
    weston --xwayland &> /dev/null &
fi
sleep 2 &&
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE='wayland'
export DISPLAY=':1'
konsole --new-tab --hide-tabbar --hide-menubar -e '/usr/bin/waydroid show-full-ui' &
while [ -n "$(pgrep weston)" ];do
    sleep 1
done
sudo systemctl stop waydroid-container.service
```

Answer (score 0):

This script works great for me, it starts weston and waydroid and when you close weston window it stops waydriod session automatically! Tested on Ubuntu and ArchLinux.

```
#!/bin/bash
export WAYLAND_DISPLAY=mysocket
weston --socket=$WAYLAND_DISPLAY --backend=x11-backend.so --width=1920 --height=1080 &
cmd1_pid=$!
waydroid show-full-ui &
wait $cmd1_pid
waydroid session stop
echo 'waydroid session stopped successfully!'
```